# IP blocked the day after using for first time

Tags: ip-address

My IP address has been "blacklisted" after using TOR for only a day. I am not using it for anything scandalous.

How do I get my IP address cleared?

The message I see when I try to search for something:

"Access denied. Your IP address is blacklisted. If you feel this is in error please contact your hosting provider's abuse department."

I am blacklisted when I try to use TOR only. I will try to contact my ISP and ask them to remove the ban. It seems unfair for them to ban TOR. It is my private business which Internet browser I use... isn't it?

Please tell me what I need to do.

Comment: Do you get this message only when using the Tor network? And are you using the Tor browser bundle (vs the tor software and SOCKS proxy)? Lastly have you made any changes to your tor configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

are you blacklisted when you use ordinary internet or when you use tor?
I think your ISP blacklisted you, so, you must ask them to remove ban. if some website blacklisted you, their server admin has network software that blacklisted you. some websites/forums recognize tor and block your IP address. it is their server admin who does it. he will not remove ban, he will stop you to use tor to visit site/forum.

Answer (score 0):

You must respect your ISP policy on Tor usage, or risk getting banned. A lot of ISPs do not permit Tor relays, and some Tor usage is banned. If they detect traffic such as Tor that is forbidden in their policy,you *will* get banned.

If you must use Tor, consider using bridges instead. They are significantly harder to detect